# Current Android Mobile Sound Profile

Tags: android

How do we know the current android mobile sound profile? I mean whether device was in either silent/meeting or etc...

Can we send the device **current profile status** to others?

Comment: @KCRaji: your first part of the question is already answered below, the other part answer is that AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT and other status are `integers` so you can send them others using internet, bluetooth or NFC.

Comment: in agreement with @AhmadKayyali , If you still think you need something more, please elaborate your question.

Comment: What about when mobile was in **Flight** mode.??

Answer (score 4):

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
        Log.i("MyApp","Silent mode");
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
        Log.i("MyApp","Vibrate mode");
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
        Log.i("MyApp","Normal mode");
        break;
}


private static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {

   return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
           Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;

}
```

Comment: What about when mobile was in **Flight** mode.??